# Get the result from 3 tables that have the same name of fields

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables in SQL Server:

Table **MyParents**

```
ID   Name   Surname
```

Table **MyCousins**

```
ID   Name   Surname
```

Table **MyGrandParents**

```
ID   Name   Surname
```

I would like to ask: is there a way to get the "Name" and "Surname" from all the 3 tables and to know from what table they are coming from in one query?

So the result should be

```
Name         Surname        Table
-----------------------------------------
Giovanni     Rossi          MyParents
Rosanna      Blu            MyCousins
Seth         TheGreat       MyGrandParents
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` and a literal for the table.

```
SELECT name,
       surname,
       'MyParents' [table]
       FROM MyParents
UNION ALL
SELECT name,
       surname,
       'MyCousins' [table]
       FROM MyCousins
UNION ALL
SELECT name,
       surname,
       'MyGrandParents' [table]
       FROM MyGrandParents;
```

But note, that your design is probably improvable. There should be only one table for all the people and a linking table storing how they are related.

Comment: I know, but the tables that I would like to make as you said are way too different and they dont really relate. But you are the master and you solved me that so quickly really appreciate it.

Comment: Hello I would like to ask you one question. Is there any other way to write `'MyParents'`, `'MyCousins'`, `'MyGrandParents'` ? Because in ASP .NET I get an empty data, meanwhile in SQL SERVER it works. I think that 
apostrophe in ASP .NET is not working as expected.

Comment: @ChangeWorld: Without seeing the .NET code that cannot be answered. Maybe open a new question including the code.